# Passing a list to an environment variable to exclude certain classes from auto configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In Spring you can exclude certain classes from autoconfiguration by defining them in the `spring.autoconfigure.exclude` property. In my case, we are using yaml to define to exclude certain classes:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: |
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsChannelAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricExportAutoConfiguration,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration
```

to exclude the actuator setup. However, as that only needs to happen in certain environments, I want to externalize this setup and pass it as an environment variable. Spring allows you to pass configuration as an environment variable of the form `SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE`, but how would I pass the list in this case? I could not find anything in Springs documentation on [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) that gave me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
export SPRING_AUTOCONFIGURE_EXCLUDE=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsDropwizardAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsChannelAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricExportAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration
```